Why does Primeng animation does not work in Angular?
I am having some problems using the library PrimeNg in Angular. The problem is that I followed the installation steps from the documentation of primeng but there are some components that does not show the animation or the popup in case of calendar. I have the similar problem with the others components that show an animation.
Problem gif
As you can see the style of primeng are correct. But only the pop up calendar does not work.
Here are my Angular version and node
Angular and node version
style code styles.scss
@import "primeng/resources/themes/lara-light-blue/theme.css";
@import "primeng/resources/primeng.css";
@import "primeicons/primeicons.css";

package.json
{
  "name": "coach-v2",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/common": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.3.0",
    "primeicons": "^7.0.0",
    "primeng": "^17.13.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^17.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.4.2"
  }
}


angular.json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "coach-v2": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/coach-v2",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "coach-v2:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "coach-v2:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "coach-v2:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


My code
<div class="card flex justify-content-center">
    <p-stepper>
        <p-stepperPanel header="Header I">
            <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-nextCallback="nextCallback" let-index="index">
                <div class="card flex flex-wrap gap-3 p-fluid">
                    <div class="flex-auto">
                        <label for="buttondisplay" class="font-bold block mb-2"> Button Display </label>
                        <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" [showIcon]="true" inputId="buttondisplay"></p-calendar>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="flex-auto">
                        <label for="icondisplay" class="font-bold block mb-2"> Icon Display </label>
                        <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date2" [iconDisplay]="'input'" [showIcon]="true" inputId="icondisplay"></p-calendar>
                    </div>
                
                    <div class="flex-auto">
                        <label for="templatedisplay" class="font-bold block mb-2"> Template Display </label>
                        <p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date3" [iconDisplay]="'input'" [showIcon]="true" inputId="templatedisplay">
                            <ng-template pTemplate="inputicon" let-clickCallBack="clickCallBack">
                                <i class="pi pi-user pointer-events-none" (click)="clickCallBack($event)"></i>
                            </ng-template>
                        </p-calendar>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex pt-4 justify-content-end">
                    <p-button label="Next" icon="pi pi-arrow-right" iconPos="right" (onClick)="nextCallback.emit()" /></div
            ></ng-template>
        </p-stepperPanel>
        <p-stepperPanel header="Header II">
            <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-prevCallback="prevCallback" let-nextCallback="nextCallback" let-index="index">
                <div class="flex flex-column h-12rem">
                    <div class="border-2 border-dashed surface-border border-round surface-ground flex-auto flex justify-content-center align-items-center font-medium">Content II</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex pt-4 justify-content-between">
                    <p-button label="Back" icon="pi pi-arrow-left" (onClick)="prevCallback.emit()" />
                    <p-button label="Next" icon="pi pi-arrow-right" iconPos="right" (onClick)="nextCallback.emit()" /></div
            ></ng-template>
        </p-stepperPanel>
        <p-stepperPanel header="Header III">
            <ng-template pTemplate="content" let-prevCallback="prevCallback" let-index="index">
                <div class="flex flex-column h-12rem">
                    <div class="border-2 border-dashed surface-border border-round surface-ground flex-auto flex justify-content-center align-items-center font-medium">Content III</div>
                </div>
                <div class="flex pt-4 justify-content-start">
                    <p-button label="Back" icon="pi pi-arrow-left" (onClick)="prevCallback.emit()" /></div
            ></ng-template>
        </p-stepperPanel>
    </p-stepper>
</div>

import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { StepperModule } from 'primeng/stepper';
import { ButtonModule } from 'primeng/button';
import { CalendarModule } from 'primeng/calendar';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-stepper',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [StepperModule,
    ButtonModule,
    CalendarModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  templateUrl: './stepper.component.html',
  styleUrl: './stepper.component.scss'
})
export class StepperComponent {
  date1: Date | undefined;

  date2: Date | undefined;

  date3: Date | undefined;
}



When you use standalone components remember add the provider provideAnimations() to your main component. See, e.g. SO
